# using a static variable in hashCode()

Tags: java, hashcode

When overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of a class, would the following approach work?

All my logic to see if the objects are equal is done in my `equals()` method. The class has a static variable (we'll call it `hashCodeReturn`) that is set to 1.

When ever the equals method reaches logic that would return false, it adds 1 to `hashCodeReturn`

The `hashCode()` then simply returns the `hashCodeReturn` value

Is there any reason this would not work?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of hashCodeReturn?

Comment: Please provide some sample code so that we can see what you mean...

Comment: I'll put the code at the bottom of the post (well, I will in 8 hours when stackoverflow lets me!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it would not work.

The hash code of two objects that are the same (e.g. the same reference) should be the same.  By returning the result of a static variable you'll break this [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified.

Comment: The static value is associated with the class, and incremented each time the equals method returns false.  This means that you could get a hashcode for A, compare B and C to false, and then get a different hashcode for A (this all assumes I've understood the question correctly!)

Comment: That is correct Jeff. So the contract would not be broken as 2 equal objects would have the same hashCode (obviously I wouldn't use 1 perhaps, maybe a random number)

Comment: @JeffFoster: yes, I deleted my comment right after you added the contract of hashcode. That made your explanation precise and showed the flaw of his approach. (+1)

Comment: @Mike: The contract would be broken, see Jeffs comment under the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Hashcode()` must return same `value` when called upon the same `object` reference but when returning a `static` value which may be have be changed when called previously and may change because that is the variable of class which may get decremented and incremented independent of its `object` and that would have changed upon next calling of `hashcode()`.